# How did Buffer create the Share Menu feature for their iOS 8 app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-extensions

[Buffer app for iOS 8](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/buffer-for-social-media-twitter/id490474324?mt=8) got a feature that lets you send an image from the new iOS 8 Share Menu to their app.
The flow is like this:

> 1. Open iOS Photos app
> 2. Select an image and tap the share icon
> 3. Select Buffer from the menu (you may need to enable it first)
> 4. Buffer app opens and the image is automatically attached in the composer window

How did they manage the part to invoke their *full* app without using a small widget like most of the other apps do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS Developer at Buffer here. So we make use of iOS 8's new extensions using a share app extension as detailed in the types here... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ We actually do invoke just an extension rather than the full app.

We use the same composer code within the app itself and the extension by having our own Cocoapod set up which is then set up as a dependency of the app and the extension target. That way we only have 1 codebase and it shares the same familiar look and feel.

To set up a share extension you can follow along with Apple's guide here... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1

Happy to answer any other questions.

Comment: Awesome, many thanks Andy! Would it be possible to invoke the full app from the Share Menu too? If so, how?

Comment: Unfortunately Apple don't offer this functionality as far as I know.

Answer (score -1):

I had that problem last week, check this documentation from Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html

Comment: also this link helped me https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/ios-8-share-extension-photos-ibm-bluemix?lang=en

Comment: Thanks but do you know of a way to invoke the "full" installed app instead of the small share dialog?

Comment: like opening the app when you share an image to it? check this one https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

Comment: Yes, the flow of the "Open In" menu but for the Share Menu. The docs you linked have nothing to do with the Share Menu though.

Comment: Try to add this on your Info.plist 

<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
 <array>
  <dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
   <string>Image</string>
   <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
   <string>Alternate</string>
   <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
   <array>
    <string>public.image</string>
   </array>
  </dict>
 </array>

Comment: then on your AppDelegate you will handle the file coming in 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation

Comment: Again, that has nothing to do with the Share Menu. Your code is to handle the "Open In" and  NOT the "Share" menu feature of iOS.

Comment: lol, sorry about that. It seems that buffer has the same implementation with tumblr's share extension with modally displaying the shareviewcontroller. It's a long read but hopefully this is what you're looking for https://github.com/tumblr/ios-extension-issues